# Чтение WSDL-файла веб-сервиса

Tags: wsdl, веб-служба, service, get

Добрый день!

**Дано:**

ASP.NET

Адрес веб-сервиса: `http://localhost:44764/wsTest.asmx`

В браузере строка `http://localhost:44764/wsTest.asmx?WSDL` открывает описание веб-вервиса.

*Найти:*

Требуется получить список все его методов и параметров этих методов.

Что я делаю: я пытаюсь прочитать WSDL-файл, и у меня все ложится. Пробовал через `ServiceDescription` - он не принимает УРЛ, пробовал подключаться через `WebRequest req2 = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:44764/wsTest.asmx?WSDL");` - тоже не вышло.

**Подскажите мне, пожалуйста, объект, который сможет вернуть мне содержимое WSDL. Или, может, я неправильную стратегию выбрал? Буду рад любой помощи.**

Спасибо вам огромное.